# Can we have a string tree (in c++)? If not, what is the fastest solution?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Consider the following example:
These are the inputs:
ASED
BTY
ASED->CWD
CWD->DTT
EI->FHK
These are just a string. They have no special meaning. But "->" indicates propagate as a clone. And I want to get DTT's father according to these entries.
 Is there a faster solution?
I did not ask about coding, I only ask about the method.

Comment: sorry can you explain what those (`ASED` `BTY` ...) means?

Comment: You can do a dfs over the tree, in O(n+m) time.

Comment: @appleapple These are just a string. They have no special meaning. But "->" indicates propagate as a clone. And I want to get DTT's father according to these entries.

Comment: Looks like a forest, not a tree: There are partitions `{ASED, CWD, DTT}`, `{BTY}` and `EI, FHK}` each forming individual trees. "I want to do this with the tree" is not a description of an algorithm that's sufficient to allow a analysis of performance.

Comment: You can make any type of graph that contains pretty much anything you want in all mainstream languages. This seems to be more of a question about structures and algorithms than about C++, but it is much too vague for anyone to be able to recommend anything.

Comment: @simsim so it should be `ASED`?

Comment: it there is no multiple links, it can be simply stored inside `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` (in `(node,parent)` form)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends if the tokens (`ASED`, `CWD`, etc.) are unique or not. Also, do you want to use only standard C++ libraries or you are open to using additional libraries.

Assuming the tokens are unique, and you want to use standard C++. There are no tree data structures in the standard C++, but in this case you don't need them to address your problem.

Assuming also that a token can have only one parent, you can revert the expression `parent -> child` to `child -> parent` (in your algorithm, not in the input list). Once done, you can store the child as a key of a `map` and the parent as a value. You will need to introduce a `stop key` as a value (ex. `NULL`) to signify that the particular key has no parent.

To extract the parent, you will need to fetch the value from the map corresponding to the child, which is the intermediate parent (the link). Next you fetch the intermediate parent to get his parent. This will be repeated until you reach the stop key.

As of complexity of this approach, depends on which type of `map` you select `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`

This algorithm can be slightly modified to support for multiple parents, in which case during the traveling you will travel all possible values for the key you are fetching, which can be done with recursion or with a stack, and you will use `std::multimap` to store the data.